# Angular 2 Material - how to set the color of a toolbar conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working with a [Angular Material toolbar](https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar) which can have three types of color: 'primary', 'accent', or 'warn'.

> The color of a  can be changed by using the color
>   property. By default, toolbars use a neutral background color based on
>   the current theme (light or dark). This can be changed to 'primary',
>   'accent', or 'warn'.

I want to change this color to "warn" if a specific condition exists. I've already tried the following things:

```
<md-toolbar color="warn">
```

Shows the warning color correctly.

```
<md-toolbar color="{{true ? 'warn' : null}}">
```

Shows the toolbar as if no color would have been set

```
<md-toolbar [attr.color]="true ? 'warn' : null">
```

Shows the toolbar as if no color would have been set

How am I supposed to set this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use attribute binding:

```
<md-toolbar [color]="true ? 'warn' : null">
```